# How to checkout into a commit that was pushed in a previous step in bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following bitbucket pipeline:

```
  branches:
    develop:
      - step: *semantic_release # Performs git push 
      - step: *deploy           # Deploys the version before the push
```

I'm looking for a way to reliably checkout into the commit that was pushed (or just the latest commit of the branch) within the deploy step, how can you do that?

I tried `git checkout $BITBUCKET_BRANCH` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford not having that release commit merged in the develop branch, a 0-hassle possible solution could be pushing it to a release branch instead.

```yaml
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: semantic release
          script:
            - ./bump
            - git branch release/develop-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
            - git commit -m "bump"
            - git push origin release/develop-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
    release/develop-*:
      - step: *deploy
```

or maybe go for tags?

```yaml
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: semantic release
          script:
            - ./bump
            - git commit -m "bump"
            - git tag v$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
            - git push --tags origin develop
  tags:
    v*:
      - step: *deploy
```